# How do we obtain SAP JCo data for tcode DB02

Tags: sap-basis, jco

To monitor Performance of SAP CCMS(Rz20), we used XM interface, like : 
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/da47d190-0201-0010-ac9a-e236663563e0?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&5003637377319

Is there any such interface for Database(DB02)? or what Functional Modules can help me fetch performance data of DB used by SAP Subsystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same CCMS modules can be used to get Database Alerts. DB Alerts should be enabled to CCMS.